# Find probability from uniform distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, independence, uniform-distribution

Let $X$, $Y$ be two independent random variables from $U(0,1)$. Then find $P[Y>(X-1/2)^2]$.

I initially  tried drawing the figure but that seemed complicated. I then took expectation on both sides and got $P[E(Y)>V(X)]$. Am I right?

Comment: What did you attempt to draw?  The drawing is very simple so the area of integration should be quite simple to figure out once you sketch the x-y plane.

Comment: Also, why are you doing anything with expectation?  You are simply asked to find the **probability**, not the expectation.

Comment: @Analyst1 Probabilities *are* expectations (of indicator variables).  Often they can readily be found using techniques to find expectations.  The mistake made here is to suppose that $E[Y\gt (X-\mu_X)^2] = E[Y \gt E[(X-\mu_X)^2]]$: this is rarely true and there are no generally applicable rules of expectation, probability, or integration that would justify such an equation.

Comment: Good point @whuber, but I don't see where the OP was headed with regard to his/her approach by finding an expectation.  The most straightforward approach to solving this problem seemed to be simply integrating the area bounded below by 0 and 1 and above the parabola $Y = (X-1/2)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

This ends up being the area above the curve
\begin{equation}
Y=(X−\frac{1}{2})^2
\end{equation}

[image]

This can be found by integration
\begin{equation}
P[Y>(X−\frac{1}{2})^2] = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{(X−\frac{1}{2})^2}^{1} 1\times1 \,dydx
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \int_{0}^{1}{1-(X−\frac{1}{2})^2} \,dx
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=  \Big[X-\frac{1}{3}\times(X−\frac{1}{2})^3\Big]_0^1  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=  \Big(1-\frac{1}{3}\times(1−\frac{1}{2})^3\Big) - \Big(0-\frac{1}{3}\times(0−\frac{1}{2})^3\Big)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=  \frac{23}{24}-\frac{1}{24}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=  \frac{22}{24}
\end{equation}